# How to find an item in a panel

Tags: python, python-2.7, user-interface, wxpython

I am using Python WX to make a large GUI containing maybe 100 CheckBoxes. I want to read the value of each checkbox and append these values to a list. I can do this with 100 lines of code but prefer to use a loop. In the loop, how can I identify or select the specific checkbox I want to get the value from?

```
self.Box1 = wx.CheckBox(self.panel, id = 1, label='first box', pos=(10, 25), size=(30,22))
self.Box2 = wx.CheckBox(self.panel, id = 2, label='second box', pos=(20, 25), size=(30,22))
          .
          .
          .
self.Box100 = wx.CheckBox(self.panel, id = 100, label='100th box', pos=(100, 25), size=(30,22))
```

Looking for something like:

```
MyList = []
for N in range (1, 101):
     MyList.append(self.Box + N.Value)
```

The more generic question here is "how to select an object name in a loop"

I have searched all day with no luck. I am not a programming expert and hope this is worthy of someone's answer.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than having 100 almost-identical lines of code, which is error-prone, inefficient and unattractive, actually build the `CheckBox`es in a loop and hold them in a list:

```
self.boxes = [] 
for i in range(1, 101):      
    self.boxes.append(wx.CheckBox(self.panel, id=i, 
                                  label="Box {0}".format(i)
                                  pos=(10, 25), size=(30,22)))
```

Then getting all of the values is similarly simple:

```
for i, box in enumerate(self.boxes, 1):
    ...
```

as is accessing a single one:

```
box = self.boxes[i-1]
```

If you really want `"first"`, `"second"`, `"100th"` write a helper function to process `i` into a string representation.

Answer (score 1):

I personally like to use widget names. For example:

```
import wx

########################################################################
class MyPanel(wx.Panel):
    """"""

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self, parent):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)

        self.sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        for i in range(5):
            txt = "Checkbox #%s" % i
            chk = wx.CheckBox(self, label=txt, name=txt)
            self.sizer.Add(chk, 0, wx.ALL|wx.CENTER, 5)

        button = wx.Button(self, label="Get check")
        button.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.onButton)
        self.sizer.Add(button, 0, wx.ALL|wx.CENTER, 5)

        self.SetSizer(self.sizer)

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def onButton(self, event):
        """"""
        widget = self.FindWindowByName("Checkbox #0")
        print widget
        print widget.GetValue()

########################################################################
class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    """"""

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title="Checkboxes")
        panel = MyPanel(self)
        self.Show()

#----------------------------------------------------------------------
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = MyFrame()
    app.MainLoop()
```

This code will create a set of 5 wx.Checkboxes that each have a unique name. Then you can look them up by name using **wx.FindWindowByName**.

You could also create a dictionary using the names as the keys and the values as the CheckBox widgets which gives the advantage of being a faster lookup.